# How do I intercept an API call and display data from it using a UserScript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey, fetch-api

There's a webapp that makes a request (let's call it `/api/item`). This request returns a json body with a field called `itemData` which is normally hidden from the user, but I want to make that shown.

So how do I make a userscript that listens for the request at `/api/item` and displays the itemData field?

For reference the way the webapp is making the request is:

```
return Promise.resolve(new Request(e,r)).then(sendCookies).then(addLangParam).then(addCacheParam).then(addXsrfKey).then(checkZeroRating).then(function(e) {
            return fetch(e)
        }).then(checkStatus).then(checkApiVersionMismatch).then(checkApiResponse)
```

Most of that is irrelevant, but the important part is `Request` (I think).

Comment: Is that code from app's service worker? You can't intercept it in a userscript. Otherwise try cloaking `fetch` or XMLHttpRequest's open/send.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried cloaking `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` - but that doesn't capture the call I want, only a bunch of random other calls. As for the fetch thing, what's fetch, and how do I cloak that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This webapp is not using XMLHttpRequest, but the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

You can use the [fetch-intercept npm module](https://github.com/werk85/fetch-intercept) to intercept fetch requests. Example code:

```
import fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept'

fetchIntercept.register({
  response(response) {
    console.log(response)
    return response
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work within a userscript.

I can't `npm install` anything from a userscript.

Comment: Just use the source code of that module as an example. There's, like, one page.

Comment: @ReverseCold actually it doesn't have any dependencies (only dev, which you should not care about). You just need to slightly tweak `index.js` to make it a javascript module, not an npm module, You can find the result that you could just include as a script [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nirvana_msu/7tjojmyy/)

Comment: @nirvana-msu Any chance you could re-post that fiddle? I have no idea why BMA deleted it... perfectly valid to post a different version (or a modified version) of an answer. Personally, I would like to see that code and I'll be others also want to see it. If code is correct, please submit another answer. However, no need to use an external resource like jsFiddle. Several years later you probably already know this (it was new in 2017) but you can press Ctrl+M in an answer to create a Stack-Snippet and keep everything local.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the promise returned ?

If so, then you may add another "then".
Otherwise, you may overwrite "checkApiResponse"